# appendChild onclick will only add div once

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener, appendchild, createelement

I'm doing a timetable and to do list website. So, I basically add divs for each timetable block. I've used this tutorial on yt (https://youtu.be/MkESyVB4oUw) for the timetable blocks. (At 24:03) So in HTML there's inputs in a form and he uses the constant "form" for it and uses an addEventListener submit. I've used this and all my timetable blocks work fine. I can add multiple blocks and everything works well.

After that I made a to do / goals section and I decided to take the "form" into my own hands. So I did:

```
// I tried const and var and the same thing happened
const todoAdd = document.querySelector("#new-todo");   // This is the button
const weekDiv = document.querySelector("#week-divs");

const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
todoDiv.classList.add("todo-div");
```

This is what I did for the time blocks and it worked, and then I added:

```
todoAdd.onclick = function(){
  weekDiv.appendChild(todoDiv);
}
```

When I do it like this, the div is added once and that's it. If I keep clicking the div just gets replaced again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out mid-writing it. Because when the addEventListener starts for the form, that's when I did all the appending. So the simple solution to this was simply adding the createElement inside the function.

```
  todoAdd.onclick = function(){
    const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
    todoDiv.classList.add("todo-div");
    
    weekDiv.appendChild(todoDiv);
  }
```

I probably could've realised this sooner if I wasn't so confused about it actually working just once. I thought there was something missing instead of a simple mistake. I'm guessing it only appends once because it is only read once, while in an onclick function or addEventListener it always loops and re-reads it right? That's my thoughts. Hope this helps someone maybe.

Comment: Nice! I'd recommend using `addEventListener('click')` instead of the `onclick` attribute though. They are different

Comment: I've used both `onclick` and `addEventListener('click')` but may I ask why you suggest the addEventListener? Is it more efficient or do more browser support it?

Comment: Give [this](https://tshlosberg.medium.com/addeventlistener-vs-onclick-which-one-should-you-use-47550d7e7487) article a read